# ReadOnly Access from windows 7 to a shared folder in ubuntu

Tags: read-only, copy

I am really new in ubuntu.

I want to share a folder in a desktop (ubuntu) and have a access for other windows 7 users in company network to see only the files and folders.

They should be able only to see the files and will not be able to copy the files or any folder.

Answer (score 1):

Windows cannot read ext4 partitions straightaway.

Using 3rd party software to access your Linux partitions is not recommended by me as it has the potential to corrupt your ext4 partition.

The best bet is to make a NTFS partition in Ubuntu and keep the files you want to share with windows over there. It is because Linux has no problem with NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 1):

To share files and folder between Linux/Ubuntu and Windows in Windows network you need to install Samba server. Type in the Terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install samba
```

*Or just start to share some file or folder and you will be asked to install it automatically.*

I hope that like a beginner you use Ubuntu Desktop.

For simple sharing use Nautilus file explorer and follow the example below.

[image]

For more complex settings you must edit Samba configuration file (make a backup copy before that):

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf 
  or
$ sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

To load the new settings: `sudo /etc/init.d/samba reload`

For this purpose, [you can use and some GUI tool](https://www.google.bg/search?q=samba%20gui%20interface&rlz=1C1CHBD_enBG704BG704&oq=samba%20gui%20interface&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6223j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) like as gadmin-samba.

```
$ sudo apt install gadmin-samba    # to install it
$ gksu gadmin-samba                # to run it
```

*Or type "gadmin" in the Unity search bar*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Also, I need to restrict the files not to copy from shared folder. The other users should be able to only see the files (for example see the photos, pdf or word) but they should not be able to copy the files to their PCs.